# Decode an escaped string from VBScript in Java

Tags: java, vbscript, character-encoding, escaping, decoding

I tried to decode the following string,

```
String str  = "AT%26amp%3BT%20Network%20Client%20%u2013%20IBM";

System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(str));
try {
    System.out.println("res:"+java.net.URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Both methods fail as below,

```
AT%26amp%3BT%20Network%20Client%20%u2013%20IBM
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u2"
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:173)
    at decrypt.DecryptHtml.main(DecryptHtml.java:19)
```

The source of the string is a VBS script that uses [the `Escape` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). How can I decode this string?

Comment: *"The source of the string is a VBS file using Escape function"* What `Escape` function? Because it looks like it's URI-encoded, but with errors. Specifically, it has `%u` in it, which is invalid in URI encoding.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()` won't work here; those are percent-encoding escapes, not HTML escape sequences.

Comment: Range of *hex* values are from `0` to `7F` on decimals `0` to `127`. The character `u` will never occur. It must be an invalid encoded string. Must be a typo, manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, from reading the documentation, it appears that Microsoft Has Done It Again (tm): "non standard xxx", where here "xxx" is "escaping format".

Specifically, in [the documentation of the VBScript function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), it is said that:

> [...]Unicode characters that have a value greater than 255 are stored using the %uxxxx format.

(Hey, MS: there is no such thing as "Unicode characters"; those are called *code points*)

Great. So you need your own decoding function.

Fortunately, we use Java. And since this proprietary escape sequence only covers Unicode code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 to U+FFFF), *and* since `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, *and* since there is a 1 to 1 mapping between BMP and UTF-16, this makes our job a *little* easier.

Here is the code:

```
public final class MSUnescaper
{
    private static final char PERCENT = '%';
    private static final char NONSTANDARD_PCT_ESCAPE = 'u';

    private MSUnescaper()
    {
    }

    public static String unescape(final String input)
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
        final CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.wrap(input);

        char c;

        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            c = buf.get();
            if (c != PERCENT) {
                sb.append(c);
                continue;
            }
            if (!buf.hasRemaining())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            c = buf.get();
            sb.append(c == NONSTANDARD_PCT_ESCAPE
                ? msEscape(buf) : standardEscape(buf, c));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static char standardEscape(final CharBuffer buf, final char c)
    {
        if (!buf.hasRemaining())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        final char[] array = { c, buf.get() };
        return (char) Integer.parseInt(new String(array), 16);
    }

    private static char msEscape(final CharBuffer buf)
    {
        if (buf.remaining() < 4)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        final char[] array = new char[4];
        buf.get(array);
        return (char) Integer.parseInt(new String(array), 16);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final String input = "AT%26amp%3BT%20Network%20Client%20%u2013%20IBM";
        System.out.println(unescape(input));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AT&amp;T Network Client – IBM
```

Comment: For it to be a unicode character `'\u2013'` to represent `_` an underscore, the string is missing the backslash before character `u`.

Comment: @Ravinder: No, the point is this is MS's "own" encoding. If they want `%u2013` to represent Unicode code point 2013, they can. (And I get `"–"`, not an underscore.)

Comment: Yes, it is hyphen not underscore. I understood on how it can be resolved. I am just trying to parse if the string "%u2013" can be converted to a unicode char. It still is missing a backslash char.

Comment: If I remove Escape function I get AT&amp;T Network Client - IBM, which I am able to decode correctly, but I ended up in another issue with another result string like "Remote Control AyĤame Premium " which when opened in browser throw up "not well formed"

Comment: @Ravinder: No, it's not missing anything. It's not a Java String unicode escape. It's a MS pseudo-URI escape.

Comment: I'd just suggest to use regex for such string pre-processing.

Comment: @AlexR no, regexes would be a waste here

Comment: @Ravinder the thing is, _this is not_ a standard escape. And even if you replace `%` with `\` in the string, it wouldn't make it any easier to decode.

Comment: @fge: I got the issue very well. I feel it was due to the method used for encoding the original string. It should have encoded `"\u2013"` to `"%5Cu2013"`.

Comment: @Ravinder not even that; for some reason, MS has decided to invent its own escaping scheme here, instead of doing it the Standard Way(tm)

Comment: Yes. Your comment just reflects mine in a different way. :)

Answer (score -1):

`String str  = "AT%26amp%3BT%20Network%20Client%20%[here]u[here]2013%20IBM"`
I think this string is invalid. `%u20` is not valid charecter.
If you remove `u` from your string you can encode it.
 For reference: [w3schools html url encodeing](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: I've changed your link title, w3schools is not in any way associated with the W3C.

Comment: THis is not what the OP asks. See the link he added to MS' doc